Defining a Function that Can Optionally Output an Arbitrary Number of Tables and Graphs
I'm importing some data from a csv file, performing various filtering operations on it, and then constructing graphs. I'm trying to define a function that does it 'all,' that supports the importing, filtering, and graphing of the final data. I'm stuck on how to get my call to TableView to be displayed. If I put it as the last statement in the module without any If semantics, it works, but I want to be able to optionally display it, along with other tables optionally as well. A function that more-or-less shows what I'm trying to do:
ClearAll[HandleRefToRef, csvFile];
Options[HandleRefToRef] = {debugOn -> False, displayImportedData -> False, displayFilteredData -> False};
HandleRefToRef[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
   {importedData, filteredData},
   If[! ValueQ[csvFile] || ! StringLength[csvFile] > 0,
    csvFile = InputString["Path to csv file?"];
    ];
   If[OptionValue[debugOn] == True, 
    Print["The path to the csv file is '" <> csvFile <> "'."]];
   importedData = Import[csvFile];
   If[OptionValue[displayImportedData] == True, TableView[importedData]];
   (* code to filter the values in importedData... *)
   If[OptionValue[displayFilteredData] == True, TableView[filteredData]];
   ];

If csvFile were already assigned with a valid path and the function was called as follows:
HandleRefToRef[]

Then nothing would be displayed. But if it were called as follows:
HandleRefToRef[displayImportedData -> True]

Then the output of TableView[importedData] would be shown.
And finally, if it were called as follows:
HandleRefToRef[displayImportedData -> True, displayFilteredData -> True]

Then both the output of TableView[importedData] and TableView[filteredData] would be shown as separate tables.
Eventually, I want to also be able to be able to output additional filterings, multiple graphical objects, etc., but for now, I'm stuck on the above.
Thanks for your consideration and any help!
Edit: I changed the title to refer to 'Function' rather than 'Module.'

No time to try your code, But I noticed you have ; at end. Try removing the last ; in your module and see if this helps. Last line in module should not have ; after it.

Thanks @Nasser. I tried that, but I still have the same issue: the function will only output a single table (the last one that doesn't have the semicolon) even if I specify that both should be output via HandleRefToRef[displayImportedData -> True, displayFilteredData -> True].

TableView is not currently supported in the Wolfram Cloud What happens if you are using the desktop version and you replace all your code above with a { followed by a newline followed by TableView[{1,2,3}] followed by a newline followed by TableView[{4,5,6}] followed by a newline followed by } and then  to see if there is any chance it displays two TableViews one above the other which you can individually edit. Please let me know what happens. I'm curious. Thanks

@Bill, changing your example to
{  TableView[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}],  TableView[{{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}]  }
I got two tables in a list.

If I understand correctly, you want several outputs for a single function. Besides Print, you can also use Echo (which is suited for debugging) and CellPrint (which is more flexible), e.g. CellPrint@ExpressionCell[some code here, "Output"]. These are side-effects, not returned value for the function.

@Lacia awesome! Using CellPrint[TableView[dataToDisplay]] does the trick. I had been wondering if I should collect everything into a dictionary (i.e., an Association in Mathematica), but this is all related to more-or-less wanting to be able to optionally display debug type output.
